# Newton-Raphson method in R, else and recursion

Tags: r, if-statement, recursion

I am doing the newton-raphson method in a very limited way.

```
x0=5; epsilon = 1e-07

new_rap1 = function(ini, eps){
  f = function(a) a*a -2;
  fpr = function(a) 2*a;
  xn1 = ini-(f(ini)/fpr(ini))
  if(abs(xn1-ini) > eps){
    new_rap(xn1, eps)
  }
  xn1
}

new_rap1(x0, epsilon)

new_rap2 = function(ini, eps){
  f = function(a) a*a -2;
  fpr = function(a) 2*a;
  xn1 = ini-(f(ini)/fpr(ini))
  if(abs(xn1-ini) > eps){
    new_rap(xn1, eps)
  } else{xn1}
}
```

with the new_rap1 function, i got *2.7* that is incorrect answer.

But new_rap2 function gives the correct answer, that is *1.414214*.

I don't know the difference between them. The only difference I see is the last else, but I do not know what makes it different.

```
new_rap1 = function(ini, eps){
  f = function(a) a*a -2;
  fpr = function(a) 2*a;
  xn1 = ini-(f(ini)/fpr(ini))
  if(abs(xn1-ini) > eps){
    new_rap1(xn1, eps)
  }
  xn1;print(1)
}
```

I tried several tests, and then I put that print statement, 1 printed 6 times.
i.e.

```
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

(I guess it is the number of recursion until the answer is reached.)

Since encountered in a recursive function before encountering the print statement, should not 1 be printed only once at the end?

Thank you.

Comment: May be a simple scoping issue, xn1 getting called inside/outside if statement may produce different results

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the recursion, the `xn1` returned by `new_rap1` is the same value after the first Newton step (that is, when the outermost call in the recursion cycle is executed), even though the recursion calculates indeed the correct value. You can see this by running the following code:

```
x0=5; epsilon = 1e-07

new_rap1 = function(ini, eps){
    f = function(a) a*a -2;
    fpr = function(a) 2*a;
    xn1 = ini-(f(ini)/fpr(ini))
    print(xn1)
    if(abs(xn1-ini) > eps){
        new_rap1(xn1, eps)
    }
    xn1
}
new_rap1(x0, epsilon)
```

The `new_rap2` does not suffer this problem, because the `else{xn1}` at the end of the first call is never evaluated :)

Incidentally: I would not use recursion for an iterative root-searching method, because under certain circumstances it might end up into an endless loop. It is best to use a `for` loop with a fixed maximum number of Newton (bisection, etc.) steps.